# Proper Way to Grant Permissions in PostgreSQL

Tags: permissions, postgresql, database-administration

I am new to PostgreSQL and am having a bit of trouble finding any information on how to grant a user permissions on the database that they own. I have read a few sources that says the owner has all permissions, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I still had to grant permissions in order to run a select statement.

I have also read quite a few things that say that PostgreSQL simply doesn't support granting to multiple tables in a database at once, so I'm hoping that they are just out-of-date.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
# Create the user
createuser -SDRPE demo

# Create the database
createdb demo -O demo

# Import schema
psql -f myfile.sql demo

# Grant Permissions
???
```

Can somebody tell me the best way to go about this? Currently, I am writing all of this inside of a Rake task, so I could technically retrieve all of the tables in the database and iterate through them, but it feels like an awful clunky solution. It seems like I am missing something. Any thoughts/comments/links would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1:** As a quick note, all of these commands are being run as root which is a superuser in the database with the `IDENT SAMEUSER` authentication specified in `pg_hba.conf` in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
psql dbname username < filename.sql
```

So you would use

```
psql demo demo < myfile.sql
```

I am not sure where your sql file is going because you are not specifying the db in your script.

Comment: Updated code to show that it is going into the demo database. Does it matter what user I use to import it?

Comment: I think the user is important. Try `psql -f myfile.sql -d demo -u demo`. This should run the commands as the demo user which should mean the objects created will be owned by the demo user.

Comment: @JoesephL - Thanks, I'll give it a try and comment.

Comment: @JoesephL - Thanks, it worked! Now the only problem is that it requires me to type the password for every myfile.sql that I import (which is only 3 at the moment, but it's still a lot of user interaction). Any idea how to change that?

Comment: You could use a `.pgpass` file in your users home dirctory. Not sure how this would work as you are running the script as root but connecting as demo using `ident`. I would try putting the file in the demo users home directory. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 1):

Some examples might be:

pretty much everything:
grant all privileges on database demo to demo;

grant some simple selects:
grant select on table foo to demo;

more than select:
grant select, insert, update, delete on table foo to demo;

More info here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-grant.html

Comment: Thanks, I think I tried this, but I'll try again and come back to comment/select an answer.

Comment: I tried `grant all privileges on database demo to demo;` but I am still getting `ERROR:  permission denied for relation whatever`. I am running 8.3.

Comment: try as postgres (instead of your superuser) in case your superuser isn't what you think it is :)

Comment: @ironchef - Yeah, that thought crossed my mind; attempted it, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is grant the user 'demo' the ability to read/write/modify the database 'demo', you are already done, because the owner of the database has all necessary privileges by default.

If you need more specific privileges for more than a single user, you can [CREATE USER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-createuser.html) a new user and [GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-grant.html) privileges to one or more objects.

For non-local access to the database I strongly recommend adjusting your [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, as my question attempted to state, what I have done is NOT granting permissions on the demo table for the demo user. I can't do a simple select statement on the table until I have executed `grant all on table_name to demo`.